# Postgress to_date and extract combine

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table in postgres:

```
+----------+-------+
| date     | money |
+----------+-------+
| 20191212 | 10    |
+----------+-------+
| 20200101 | 20    |
+----------+-------+
| 20200102 | 30    |
+----------+-------+
```

I would like to create 2 queries which group by sum money by year and one query by month. The date column is varchar and I cant convert it to date.

```
+------+-------+
| year | money |
+------+-------+
| 2019 | 10    |
+------+-------+
| 2020 | 50    |
+------+-------+
```

```
+---------+-------+
| month   | money |
+---------+-------+
| 2019-12 | 10    |
+---------+-------+
| 2020-01 | 50    |
+---------+-------+
```

I tried to combine the to_date and the extract function but it does not work:

```
WITH date_year AS (
    SELECT to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD') as date_year from sales
)
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_year) as year, sum(money) as sum FROM sales group by year
```

```
WITH date_month AS (
    SELECT to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD') as date_month from sales
)
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_month) as month, sum(money) as sum FROM sales group by month
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions or aliases in `group by` clause:

```
select extract(year from to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD')) as y_year, sum(money) as sum 
from sales 
group by y_year

select extract(year from to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD')) || '-' || extract(month from to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD')) as year_month, sum(money) as sum 
from sales 
group by year_month
```

I used `y_year` because `year` is reserved in postgres.

You might also consider using `date_trunc`:

```
select date_trunc('month', to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD')) as year_month, sum(money) as sum 
from sales 
group by year_month
```

Comment: I have got "Query execution failed" because the date filed is varchar type and thats why I want to convert with to_date before extract.

Comment: @ZsoltJanes ach, ok. So you need to use `date` instead. It has a temporal type, right?

Comment: Yes i know the date type would be better, but I can not change the type it should be varchar(8).

Comment: Thanks for your previous helps, i found the sollution: 
select to_char(date_trunc('month', to_date(date, 'YYYYMMDD')), 'YYYY-MM') as month, sum(money) as sum
from sales
group by month
order by month ASC